# MySQL- get id of next insert

Tags: mysql, insert

I am building a system whereby the user can build pages for a blog. The pages can contain images which obviously require manipulation and storage in folders. I am using the id of the SQL table row where the page data is stored as the basis for the folder name which stores the images for that page. The trouble is, sometimes this folder has to be created BEFORE the other page data has been inserted into the SQL table.

SO... how do I find what the ID of the NEXT insert will be?

I can't use the SELECT MAX(id) + 1 because pages may have been deleted in the meantime, reducing the max ID.

Any ideas? I am using codeigniter, so if anyone knows a library or method in CI that deals with this problem, that'd be ideal.

I COULD insert a dummy row, get the ID, delete it, then add one to the value, but seems like a bit of a hack?

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL is not a DBMS but a database language. Would you please tag it accordingly?

Comment: You cant do  insert a dummy row, get the ID, delete it, then add one to the value.because may be pages are added and deleted during the time you do this process.

Comment: Hi vikiii, this won't be an issue fortunately, as there is only one user- it's a private system.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LAST_INSERT_ID() function.

Comment: Hi Zuker, can't do that, in my question I state that this needs to be done BEFORE the data is inserted

Comment: http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/ ???

Comment: Thanks, J. It looks like that might hold a solution... rather complicated though, I had hoped there might be an easier way. I'm inclined to just use my dummy-row method I think! Thanks though!

Comment: OK, here's solution from Drupal CMS - it uses special "sequences" table with two columns - for sequence identifier and sequence itself. So whenever you need an ID you need to get it's sequence by idenitifier and increment this sequence.